# Add cell to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can't handle simple problem - adding cells to `UITableView`.

I have single-view application, with added from Objects - Table View and simple `NSArray` (deseriliazed json from internet-grabbed data).

```
- (void) didLoadMusicList:(APIDownload *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Music list loaded");
    CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer new];

    NSDictionary *dict = [deserializer deserializeAsDictionary:request.downloadData error:nil];

    NSArray *response = [dict objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSArray *audios = [response subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, response.count-1)];      

    for(int i = 0; i < audios.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *audio = [audios objectAtIndex:i];

        // add a cell?
    }
}
```

So, how do I add cell for each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the UITableViewDatasource on your view controller. You can use the same array to provide the data to the cells, and return them using the cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method. You also need to provide with the count of cells on your tableView.

Check this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have implemented `UITableViewDataSource`, provided nubmer  of sections and number of rows in section, connected dataSource to View Controller... But I still don't get how I supposed to pass my array to TableView. %)

Comment: you do not pass the array to the table view. The table view, when needs the data, will ask the datasource for data on the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. There, you will use your data array to provide data to your tableviewcell and return it.